# Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell, nan

I have created a Pandas DataFrame

```py
df = DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])
```

Now, I would like to assign a value to particular cell, for example to row `C` and column `x`. In other words, I would like to perform the following transformation:

```
     x    y             x    y
A  NaN  NaN        A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN   ⟶   B  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN        C   10  NaN
```

with this code:

```py
df.xs('C')['x'] = 10
```

However, the contents of `df` has not changed. The dataframe contains yet again only `NaN`s. How do I what I want?

Comment: Don't use 'chained indexing' (`df['x']['C']`), use `df.ix['x','C']`.

Comment: The order of index access needs to be: `dataframe[column (series)] [row (Series index)]`, whereas many people (including myself) are more used to the `dataframe[row][column]` order. As a Matlab and R programmer the latter feels more intuitive to me but that apparently is not the way Pandas works..

Comment: i tried that, but i ended up adding another row names x and another column names C. you have to do the row first then the column. so df.ix['C','x']=10

Comment: To @Yariv's comment.  Warning: Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html .  df.at looks like it is sticking around.

Comment: Be sure to check (and upvote to undig) Atta Jutt’s answer if you need to change values for a whole subset of the dataframe using the index values.

Comment: Note that iteratively setting values is a pandas anti-pattern. That said, I have occasionally done it as a way of collecting results of asycio "parallel" computations on rows

Answer (score 940, accepted):

[RukTech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517695/190597), `df.set_value('C', 'x', 10)`, is far and away faster than the options I've suggested below. However, it has been [**slated for deprecation**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15269).

Going forward, the [recommended method is `.iat/.at`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15269#issuecomment-276382712).

---

**Why `df.xs('C')['x']=10` does not work:**

`df.xs('C')` by default, returns a new dataframe [with a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas.DataFrame.xsY) of the data, so

```
df.xs('C')['x']=10
```

modifies this new dataframe only.

`df['x']` returns a view of the `df` dataframe, so

```
df['x']['C'] = 10
```

modifies `df` itself.

**Warning**: It is sometimes difficult to predict if an operation returns a copy or a view. For this reason the [docs recommend avoiding assignments with "chained indexing"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

---

So the recommended alternative is

```
df.at['C', 'x'] = 10
```

which *does* modify `df`.

---

```
In [18]: %timeit df.set_value('C', 'x', 10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit df['x']['C'] = 10
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.31 µs per loop

In [81]: %timeit df.at['C', 'x'] = 10
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `df.x` in the [API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html). What did you mean?

Comment: @smci: `'x'` is the name of a column in `df`. `df.x` returns a `Series` with the values in column `x`. I'll change it to `df['x']` since this notation will work with any column name (unlike the dot notation) and I think is clearer.

Comment: I knew that, I thought you were saying `df.x` was some unknown new method alongside `df.xs, df.ix`

Comment: `df.xs(..., copy=True)` returns a copy, and that's the default behavior. `df.xs(..., copy=False)` returns the original.

Comment: According to the maintainers, this is not the recommended way to set a value. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21287235/1579844 and my answer.

Comment: Sometimes chaining is painful if you have a big index column like datetime. You can't type it every time.

Comment: In my case I had a mix, i.e. index location and column label. I found this way to get it to work : `df_temp.iat[0, df_temp.columns.get_loc('Cash')] = df_temp['Cash'].iloc[0] + start_val`

Comment: square brackets [] after a method is confusing to me `at[...]`... why aren't they normal parenthesis ()?

Comment: `df.at['C', 'x'] = 10` is quite useful its just in the opposite way as the way it's written is misleading.... try this `df.at[position, label]` were `position` is the row number and `label` is the column name

Answer (score 264):

Update: The `.set_value` method is going to be [deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15269). `.iat/.at` are good replacements, unfortunately pandas provides little documentation

---

The fastest way to do this is using [set_value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html). This method is ~100 times faster than `.ix` method. For example:

```py
df.set_value('C', 'x', 10)
```

Comment: It's even better than `df['x']['C'] = 10 `.

Comment: 1000 loops, best of 3: **195 µs** per loop "df['x']['C'] = 10"
1000 loops, best of 3: **310 µs** per loop "df.ix['C','x'] = 10"
1000 loops, best of 3: **189 µs** per loop "df.xs('C', copy=False)['x'] = 10"
1000 loops, best of 3: **7.22 µs** per loop "df.set_value('C', 'x', 10)"

Comment: does this also work for adding a new row/col to the dataframe?

Comment: Yes it does (for pandas 0.16.2)

Comment: Is it possible to use this to set a value to a `df=df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True),ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: @RukTech, really it is the [fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index/56024454#56024454) at the moment.

Comment: As for today, I used the `.at` construct, and worked like a charm... `df['x'].at['C'] = 10.0`

Comment: Seems to be deprecated https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

Answer (score 168):

You can also use a conditional lookup using `.loc` as seen here:

```
df.loc[df[<some_column_name>] == <condition>, [<another_column_name>]] = <value_to_add>
```

where `<some_column_name` is the column you want to check the `<condition>` variable against and `<another_column_name>` is the column you want to add to (can be a new column or one that already exists). `<value_to_add>` is the value you want to add to that column/row.

This example doesn't work precisely with the question at hand, but it might be useful for someone wants to add a specific value based on a condition.

Comment: the second column needs to be on brackets, otherwise all of columns will be overwritten with value. Like this: `df.loc[df['age']==3, ['age-group']] = 'toddler'`

Comment: I can't get this to work when <some_column_name> is my index (unixtime index say) and I'm trying to add a timestamp which doesn't exit yet (i.e. a new timestamp reading). Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible to change a value based on the index and cell values?

Comment: @BND I'm not sure, but you could get around this apparent pitfall but simply duplicating the index column with another column with the same value? The short answer is I don't know.

Comment: @yeliabsalohcin see above answer.

Comment: @Blairg23, oooh, thank you very much! I've spent the half of the day trying to understand how to write this using .loc.

Answer (score 82):

Try using `df.loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: This code is not working (or no longer working?) because it does not replace the value.

Comment: Note: I've used this method to set values to `None`, however, Pandas expects the column to already exist; otherwise it may set a wrong value - in my case it was `NaN` which led to other problems. If the column doesn't exist, Pandas gives a hidden `AttributeError` that I was only able to read during debugging.

Answer (score 50):

The recommended way (according to the maintainers) to set a value is:

```
df.ix['x','C']=10
```

Using 'chained indexing' (`df['x']['C']`) may lead to problems.

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287235/1579844
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
- https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6031

Comment: `ix` is deprecated: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix

Comment: works perfect! although it gonna be deprecated sometime!

Comment: As of today (and Pandas version 1.4.4) `ix` appears to no longer be supported at all. (i.e. it isn't present in the API)

Answer (score 34):

This is the only thing that worked for me!

```
df.loc['C', 'x'] = 10
```

Learn more about `.loc` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Comment: did `.loc` replace `.iat/.at`?

Comment: `at` Similar to `loc`, in that both provide label-based lookups. Use `at` if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series. From [padas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

Comment: Nice this worked for me when my index elements were numerical.

Comment: This doesn't work for a mix of numerical and string indices.

Answer (score 32):

To set values, use:

```
df.at[0, 'clm1'] = 0
```

- The fastest recommended method for setting variables.
- `set_value`, `ix` have been deprecated.
- No warning, unlike `iloc` and `loc`

Comment: I came up to the exactly [same conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index/56024454#56024454).

Answer (score 26):

`.iat/.at` is the good solution.
Supposing you have this simple data_frame:

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8   4 
1  3   9   6
2  22 33  52
```

if we want to modify the value of the cell `[0,"A"]` u can use one of those solution :

1. `df.iat[0,0] = 2`
2. `df.at[0,'A'] = 2`

And here is a complete example how to use `iat` to get and set a value of cell :

```
def prepossessing(df):
  for index in range(0,len(df)): 
      df.iat[index,0] = df.iat[index,0] * 2
  return df
```

y_train before :

```
    0
0   54
1   15
2   15
3   8
4   31
5   63
6   11
```

y_train after calling prepossessing function that `iat` to change to multiply the value of each cell by 2:

```
     0
0   108
1   30
2   30
3   16
4   62
5   126
6   22
```

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest:

```
df.loc[index_position, "column_name"] = some_value
```

To modifiy multiple cells at the same time:

`df.loc[start_idx_pos: End_idx_pos, "column_name"] = some_value`

Answer (score 9):

## Avoid Assignment with Chained Indexing

You are dealing with an [assignment with chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) which will result in a `SettingWithCopy` [warning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). This should be avoided by all means.

Your assignment will have to resort to one single `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]` slice, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799571/2192488). Hence, in your case:

```py
df.loc['C', 'x'] = 10
```

Answer (score 8):

In my example i just change it in selected cell

```
    for index, row in result.iterrows():
        if np.isnan(row['weight']):
            result.at[index, 'weight'] = 0.0
```

'result' is a dataField with column 'weight'

Answer (score 8):

Here is a summary of the valid solutions provided by all users, for data frames indexed by integer and string.

`df.iloc`, `df.loc` and `df.at` work for both type of data frames, `df.iloc` only works with row/column integer indices, `df.loc` and `df.at` supports for setting values using column names and/or integer indices.

When the specified index does not exist, both `df.loc` and `df.at` would append the newly inserted rows/columns to the existing data frame, but `df.iloc` would raise `"IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds"`. A working example tested in Python 2.7 and 3.7 is as follows:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(3), columns=['x','y','z'])
df1['x'] = ['A','B','C']
df1.at[2,'y'] = 400

# rows/columns specified does not exist, appends new rows/columns to existing data frame
df1.at['D','w'] = 9000
df1.loc['E','q'] = 499

# using df[<some_column_name>] == <condition> to retrieve target rows
df1.at[df1['x']=='B', 'y'] = 10000
df1.loc[df1['x']=='B', ['z','w']] = 10000

# using a list of index to setup values
df1.iloc[[1,2,4], 2] = 9999
df1.loc[[0,'D','E'],'w'] = 7500
df1.at[[0,2,"D"],'x'] = 10
df1.at[:, ['y', 'w']] = 8000

df1
>>> df1
     x     y     z     w      q
0   10  8000   NaN  8000    NaN
1    B  8000  9999  8000    NaN
2   10  8000  9999  8000    NaN
D   10  8000   NaN  8000    NaN
E  NaN  8000  9999  8000  499.0
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use `.iloc`.

```python
df.iloc[[2], [0]] = 10
```

Comment: This method seems not supporting several values, e.g. `df.iloc[[2:8], [0]] = [2,3,4,5,6,7]` which the method `df.loc()` does natively.

Answer (score 6):

`set_value()` is deprecated.

Starting from the release 0.23.4, Pandas "*announces the future*"...

```
>>> df
                   Cars  Prices (U$)
0               Audi TT        120.0
1 Lamborghini Aventador        245.0
2      Chevrolet Malibu        190.0
>>> df.set_value(2, 'Prices (U$)', 240.0)
__main__:1: FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead

                   Cars  Prices (U$)
0               Audi TT        120.0
1 Lamborghini Aventador        245.0
2      Chevrolet Malibu        240.0
```

Considering this advice, here's a demonstration of how to use them:

- **by row/column integer positions**

---

```
>>> df.iat[1, 1] = 260.0
>>> df
                   Cars  Prices (U$)
0               Audi TT        120.0
1 Lamborghini Aventador        260.0
2      Chevrolet Malibu        240.0
```

- **by row/column labels**

---

```
>>> df.at[2, "Cars"] = "Chevrolet Corvette"
>>> df
                  Cars  Prices (U$)
0               Audi TT        120.0
1 Lamborghini Aventador        260.0
2    Chevrolet Corvette        240.0
```

References:

- [pandas.DataFrame.iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat)
- [pandas.DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

Answer (score 6):

One way to use index with condition is first get the index of all the rows that satisfy your condition and then simply use those row indexes in a multiple of ways

```
conditional_index = df.loc[ df['col name'] <condition> ].index
```

Example condition is like

```
==5, >10 , =="Any string", >= DateTime
```

Then you can use these row indexes in variety of ways like

1. Replace value of one column for conditional_index

```
df.loc[conditional_index , [col name]]= <new value>
```

2. Replace value of multiple column for conditional_index

```
df.loc[conditional_index, [col1,col2]]= <new value>
```

3. One benefit with saving the conditional_index is that you can assign value of one column to another column with same row index

```
df.loc[conditional_index, [col1,col2]]= df.loc[conditional_index,'col name']
```

This is all possible because .index returns a array of index which .loc can use with direct addressing so it avoids traversals again and again.

Comment: what about changing rows ?

Comment: just use,
df.loc[conditional_index, ]= <new value>
It will replace new value in all columns of rows which satisfy the condition

Answer (score 5):

I tested and the output is `df.set_value` is little faster, but the official method `df.at` looks like the fastest non deprecated way to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 100))

%timeit df.iat[50,50]=50 # ✓
%timeit df.at[50,50]=50 #  ✔
%timeit df.set_value(50,50,50) # will deprecate
%timeit df.iloc[50,50]=50
%timeit df.loc[50,50]=50

7.06 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5.52 µs ± 64.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3.68 µs ± 80.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
98.7 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
109 µs ± 1.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note this is setting the value for a single cell. For the vectors `loc` and `iloc` should be better options since they are vectorized.

Answer (score 5):

If one wants to change the cell in the position (0,0) of the df to a string such as `'"236"76"'`, the following options will do the work:

```
df[0][0] = '"236"76"'
# %timeit df[0][0] = '"236"76"'
# 938 µs ± 83.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Or using [`pandas.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

```
df.at[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
#  %timeit df.at[0, 0] = '"236"76"' 
#15 µs ± 2.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Or using [`pandas.DataFrame.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)

```
df.iat[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
#  %timeit df.iat[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
# 41.1 µs ± 3.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Or using [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc)

```
df.loc[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
#  %timeit df.loc[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
# 5.21 ms ± 401 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Or using [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)

```
df.iloc[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
#  %timeit df.iloc[0, 0] = '"236"76"'
# 5.12 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If time is of relevance, using [`pandas.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is the fastest approach.

Answer (score 5):

Have been frustrated by multiple answers given with loc and .iloc such as

```
df.loc[index_position, "column_name"] = some_value
```

because when trying this they continue to throw errors or warnings, such as

`Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

and

`SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

**however, would like to clarify to others having this issue that **

```
df.at[2, "Cars"] = mystuff
```

eliminated the warning for me and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Soo, your question to convert NaN at ['x',C] to value 10

the answer is..

```
df['x'].loc['C':]=10
df
```

alternative code is

```
df.loc['C', 'x']=10
df
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc['c','x']=10`
This will change the value of *c*th row and
 *x*th column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change values not for whole row, but only for some columns:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
x.iloc[1] = dict(A=10, B=-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.21.1 you can also use `.at` method. There are some differences compared to `.loc` as mentioned here - [pandas .at versus .loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc), but it's faster on single value replacement

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, here is a benchmark comparing different ways to add rows of data to an already existing dataframe. It shows that using at or set-value is the most efficient way for large dataframes (at least for these test conditions).

- Create new dataframe for each row and...

  - ... append it (13.0 s)
  - ... concatenate it (13.1 s)
- Store all new rows in another container first, convert to new dataframe once and append...

  - container = lists of lists (2.0 s)
  - container = dictionary of lists (1.9 s)
- Preallocate whole dataframe, iterate over new rows and all columns and fill using

  - ... at (0.6 s)
  - ... set_value (0.4 s)

For the test, an existing dataframe comprising 100,000 rows and 1,000 columns and random numpy values was used. To this dataframe, 100 new rows were added.

Code see below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Nov 21 16:38:46 2018

@author: gebbissimo
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

NUM_ROWS = 100000
NUM_COLS = 1000
data = np.random.rand(NUM_ROWS,NUM_COLS)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

NUM_ROWS_NEW = 100
data_tot = np.random.rand(NUM_ROWS + NUM_ROWS_NEW,NUM_COLS)
df_tot = pd.DataFrame(data_tot)

DATA_NEW = np.random.rand(1,NUM_COLS)


#%% FUNCTIONS

# create and append
def create_and_append(df):
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
        df_new = pd.DataFrame(DATA_NEW)
        df = df.append(df_new)
    return df

# create and concatenate
def create_and_concat(df):
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
        df_new = pd.DataFrame(DATA_NEW)
        df = pd.concat((df, df_new))
    return df


# store as dict and 
def store_as_list(df):
    lst = [[] for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW)]
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
        for j in range(NUM_COLS):
            lst[i].append(DATA_NEW[0,j])
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(lst)
    df_tot = df.append(df_new)
    return df_tot

# store as dict and 
def store_as_dict(df):
    dct = {}
    for j in range(NUM_COLS):
        dct[j] = []
        for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
            dct[j].append(DATA_NEW[0,j])
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(dct)
    df_tot = df.append(df_new)
    return df_tot




# preallocate and fill using .at
def fill_using_at(df):
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
        for j in range(NUM_COLS):
            #print("i,j={},{}".format(i,j))
            df.at[NUM_ROWS+i,j] = DATA_NEW[0,j]
    return df


# preallocate and fill using .at
def fill_using_set(df):
    for i in range(NUM_ROWS_NEW):
        for j in range(NUM_COLS):
            #print("i,j={},{}".format(i,j))
            df.set_value(NUM_ROWS+i,j,DATA_NEW[0,j])
    return df


#%% TESTS
t0 = time.time()    
create_and_append(df)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()    
create_and_concat(df)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()    
store_as_list(df)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()    
store_as_dict(df)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()    
fill_using_at(df_tot)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

t0 = time.time()    
fill_using_set(df_tot)
t1 = time.time()
print('Needed {} seconds'.format(t1-t0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the underlying array of a *cell*.

`values`/`to_numpy()` returns a view of the underlying array of a DataFrame, so if a particular value in the array is changed, the change is reflected on the DataFrame as well.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])

# change the last value in the first column
df.values[-1, 0] = 10
df.to_numpy()[-1, 0] = 10


     x    y
A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN
C   10  NaN
```

You can also select a column, view its underlying array and change it by index as well. This method works even if the dtype is Extension Dtype.

```py
# change the last value in column 'x'
df['x'].values[-1] = 100
```

Changing the DataFrame view the fastest way (5 times faster than the next fastest method) to set a value in a cell, which becomes relevant if this is done in a loop.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['x', 'y'])
%timeit df.values[-1, 0] = 10   # 1.89 µs ± 85.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
%timeit df.iat[-1, 0] = 10      # 10.9 µs ± 380 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit df.at['C', 'x'] = 10    # 13 µs ± 307 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit df.loc['C', 'x'] = 10   # 55.4 µs ± 6.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit df.iloc[-1, 0] = 10     # 39.7 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -4):

I too was searching for this topic and I put together a way to iterate through a DataFrame and update it with lookup values from a second DataFrame.  Here is my code.

```
src_df = pd.read_sql_query(src_sql,src_connection)
for index1, row1 in src_df.iterrows():
    for index, row in vertical_df.iterrows():
        src_df.set_value(index=index1,col=u'etl_load_key',value=etl_load_key)
        if (row1[u'src_id'] == row['SRC_ID']) is True:
            src_df.set_value(index=index1,col=u'vertical',value=row['VERTICAL'])
```