# what's the difference between set_value and = in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In writing to a dataframe in `pandas`, we see we have a couple of ways to do it, as provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729853/set-value-for-a-selected-cell-in-pandas-dataframe).

We have the method of

- `df[r][c].set_value(r,c,some_value)` and the method of
- `df.iloc[r][c] = some_value`.

What is the difference? Which is faster? Is either a copy?

Comment: Per your own posted answers, it looks like it's a matter of speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `set_value` is *returning* an object, while the assignment operator assigns the value into the existing `DataFrame` object.

after calling `set_value` you will potentially have *two* `DataFrame` objects (this does not necessarily mean you'll have two copies of the data, as `DataFrame` objects can "reference" one another) while the assignment operator will change data in the single `DataFrame` object.

It appears to be faster to use the `set_value`, as it is probably optimized for that use-case, while the assignment approach will generate intermediate slices of the data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,100))

In [4]: %timeit df[10][10]=7
The slowest run took 6.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.5 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit df.set_value(10,10,11)
The slowest run took 10.89 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.94 µs per loop
```

the result of `set_value` *may* be a copy, but the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) is not really clear (to me) on this:

> Returns:
>
> frame : DataFrame
>
> If label pair is contained, will be reference to calling DataFrame, otherwise a new object