# Move object in pandas DataFrame from one "cell" to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to move an object in a pandas DataFrame from one location to another, and leave the original location of that object blank without affecting other columns.

```
employees = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Employees":employees, "Level":levels})

#move employee 1 from index 3 to index 1 without altering Level column
#leave index 3 blank after moving employee 1
```

Visually, I need to go from [starting point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcSSa.png) to [end point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIvOJ.png).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. You can just use the `.loc` function which takes the index as first argument and the column name as second argument.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729853/set-value-for-a-selected-cell-in-pandas-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

employees = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Employees":employees, "Level":levels})

#substitution logic
temp = df['Employees'][3]
df.loc[3, 'Employees'] = ''
df.loc[1, 'Employees'] = temp
#print output
print df
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Employees  Level
0         0      1
1         1      2
2         0      3
3                4
4         0      5
5         0      6
6         0      7
7         0      8
8         0      9
9         0     10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Employees":['','','','empployee_object','','','','','',''], 
                   "Level":range(1,11)}, index=range(1,11))
print (df)
           Employees  Level
1                         1
2                         2
3                         3
4   empployee_object      4
5                         5
6                         6
7                         7
8                         8
9                         9
10                       10

#move value from 4 index to 2 index in Employees column
df.loc[2, 'Employees'] = df.loc[4, 'Employees']
#set empty string to original
df.loc[4, 'Employees'] = ''
print (df)
           Employees  Level
1                         1
2   empployee_object      2
3                         3
4                         4
5                         5
6                         6
7                         7
8                         8
9                         9
10                       10
```