# pandas Dataframe, MOVE Specific Value from One Cell to Another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to be able to copy the values under the allergy column there are three languages. I want use pandas Dataframes to move specific cell values data from the row English to french above it and dutch underneath it. And After it's been copied, I want to delete the row English.

**Note: Index is the languages below. They go in the order of French, English, Dutch, French, English, Dutch and so on. the Values of each are the typical responses are given under the column allergy**

```
Index       allergy 

french      ''

english     'MAY CONTAIN: prawn' 

dutch       ''

french      ''

english     'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

dutch       ''

french      ''

english     'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

dutch       ''
```

So again to summarise, copy specific cell values from English to Dutch and French Rows.

edit: I cant any more comments: Yes this is the pattern for this dataset. this ouput is displayed in excel file.

**Desired output:**

```
Index        allergy 

french      'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

english     'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'  # remove

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts' 

english     'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'  # remove

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

english     'MAY CONTAIN: milk'  # remove

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Afterwards, it Should look like this

**Final output:**

```
Index        allergy 

french      'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts' 

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'

french      'MAY CONTAIN: milk'

dutch       'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Comment: Can you add data sample - 5, 6 rows with desired output?

Comment: i've updated the to show desired output @jezrael

Comment: OK, thank you. But try to imagine you want solve this question with data what can see. Is it possible? I think not :( Because I think your real data are different, not always all empty values. Or need only copy column `english` 2 times? I think creating [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should help.

Comment: Also input is dataframe with lists? What is `print (df.head())` ?

Comment: It was very usefull edit. Give em some time.

Comment: No, now it is OK. Only one thing, last need remove all `english` rows, right?

Comment: There is alwasys this format? empty french, filled englis, empty dutch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter only `english` rows and create default index:

```
df1 = df.loc['english'].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
                  allergy
0    'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'
1  'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'
2     'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) twice, sorting and last remove second level:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df1], keys=('french','dutch'))
        .sort_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
      )
print (df)
                       allergy
french    'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'
dutch     'MAY CONTAIN: prawn'
french  'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'
dutch   'MAY CONTAIN: peanuts'
french     'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
dutch      'MAY CONTAIN: milk'
```

Comment: I got  `TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'`

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: the version is 0.16.2, I need it for my project

Comment: I find it, need change `.sort_index(level=1)` to `.sortlevel(level=1)`

Comment: can I ask one more thing? is it possible to select allergy column. i.e in the excel, it shows the allergy column in D(allergy). so I ONLY want  COLUMN D(allergy) to be changed, in this case, to change and not the rest of the columns. the index is column B.

Comment: I think no easy way, necessary is read all data from excel to DataFrame, change it and write back :(

Comment: is there a way to say Column D(onwards) instead? change and not the whole thing?

Comment: Not sure, try create question... I really dont know, sorry :(

Comment: similar to [LIKE THIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746822/move-object-in-pandas-dataframe-from-one-cell-to-another)

Comment: I think no, it is something different ;(