# Python issue setting values using .ix[]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I am trying to set or floor values which go beyond a defined threshold. I am using the .ix[] method for it. However, I am unable to get it done using the below is the code (python 2).

Please teach me why this is wrong & any other faster methods.

```
df = DataFrame({"v1" : np.random.randn(10), "v2" : np.random.randn(10), "v3" : [np.nan]*10})

print "pre floor"
print df 

f_dict = {"v1": 0, "v2": 0}
#flooring value treatment
for key, val in f_dict.iteritems():
    print df.ix[df[key]<val,key] = val

print df 

#ERROR:
    print df.ix[df[key]<val,key]=0
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: .ix is going to deprecate , using .loc and .iloc

Answer (score 2):

So here is what is happening with your solution

```
  print df.ix[df[key]<val,key] = val #syntax error
```

Here you are trying to print and also assign it to variable val but that's not supportable.

> The code below serves as e example for you.

```
    df.loc[df[key]<val,key] = val
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for key, val in f_dict.iteritems():
    df.loc[df[key]<val, key] = val
print df
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729853/set-value-for-a-selected-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) for a related answer