# Add a tuple to a specific cell of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, dataframe

Just when I thought I was getting the hang of Python and Pandas, another seemingly simple issue crops up. I want to add tuples to specific cells of a pandas dataframe. These tuples need to be calculated on-the-fly based on the contents of other cells in the dataframe - in other words, I can't easily calculate all tuples in advance and add them as a single array.

As an example, I define a dataframe with some data and add a couple of empty columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'miscdata': [1.2,3.2,4.1,2.3,3.3,2.5,4.3,2.5,2.2,4.2]})
tempDF['newValue'] = np.nan
tempDF['newTuple'] = np.nan
```

I can scroll through each cell of the 'newValue' column and add an integer value without problems:

```
anyOldValue = 3.5
for i in range(10):
    tempDF.ix[(i,'newValue')] = anyOldValue

print tempDF
```

However, if I try to add a tuple I get an error message:

```
anyOldTuple = (2.3,4.5)
for i in range(10):
    tempDF.ix[(i,'newTuple')] = anyOldTuple

print tempDF
```

I've received several error messages including:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

…and…

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I'm sure I've seen data frames with tuples (or lists) in the cells - haven't I? Any suggestions how to get this code working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `set_value`:

```
tempDF.set_value(i,'newTuple', anyOldTuple)
```

Also make sure that the column is not a float column, for example:

```
tempDF['newTuple'] = 's' # or set the dtype
```

otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: That did the trick - thank you! Your second comment was very important to avoid error message.

Comment: Always use get_value() and set_value() instead of ix and others, when possible +1 for that :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html

Comment: And more detail on set_value() vs. df[value][value] for MultiIndexing etc http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Thanks! Although in the meantime, set_value is deprecated and we should use `tempDF.iat[i, 'newTuple'] = anyOldTuple` instead: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

Comment: None of these work for me. I get a vague `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.

Answer (score 3):

set_value is deprecated.

you can just use .at[] or iat[]

e.g. `some_df.at[ idx, col_name] = any_tuple`

Comment: Thanks! Perfect Answer for my problem ! :)

Answer (score 1):

As [J.Melody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54739305) pointed out, `.at[]` and `.iat[]` can be used to assign a tuple to a cell, if the dtype of the column is `object`.

**Minimal example:**

```
df initialized as:
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df containing tuple:
   a       b  c
0  0  (1, 2)  2
1  3       4  5
2  6       7  8
```

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)), columns=list('abc'), dtype=object)
print('df initialized as:', df, sep='\n')
df.at[0,'b'] = (1,2)
print()
print('df containing tuple:', df, sep='\n')
```

**Note:**

If you skip `, dtype=object`, you end up with

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tempDF.at[i,'newTuple', anyOldTuple]`. `set_value` deprecated