# Overwrite a single conditionally selected cell in a (geo)pandas (geo)dataframe with external data in tuple or geopy.location.Location format

Tags: pandas, tuples, geopandas, geopy

I start with a pandas dataframe of historical places. I pass a column of place names to geopy for geocoding. I extract the coordinates, and turn them into points. I also save the geocoder's returned geopy.location.Location in a column for further use.  This all seems to work fine if I run it on the whole (geo)dataframe.

The problem arises when I want to overwrite a few of the entries. For instance, I want to overwrite wherever the geocoder has tried and failed to locate 'Fargo N Dak' (the historical abbreviation) correctly. I can re-run the geocoder on a single, modernized place name and extract the data, but I can't figure out how to insert it in the original gdf.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

#set up Nominatim geocoder with geopy package with a user_agent (required) and a rate limiter
Ngeocoder0 = Nominatim(user_agent="aGeocoder")
Ngeocoder = RateLimiter(Ngeocoder0.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

#make some toy data
lst = ['Minneapolis MN', 'Fargo ND', 'Fargo N Dak'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns =['rawPOB'])

df['_TEMP'] = df['rawPOB'].apply(lambda x: Ngeocoder(x, language='en',addressdetails=True))

df['rawGCcoords']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[1], x.point[0]) if x else None)
df['rawGClong']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[1]) if x else None)
df['rawGClat']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[0]) if x else None)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['rawGClong'], df['rawGClat']))


#so far so good, except Fargo N Dak is not recognized as Fargo North Dakota
#code just this place...
manualentry= Ngeocoder('Fargo North Dakota', language='en',addressdetails=True)
manualcoords=(manualentry.point[1], manualentry.point[0])

#... but here it all goes wrong when try to insert
gdf.loc[gdf.rawPOB == 'Fargo N Dak', '_TEMP'] = manualentry
gdf.loc[gdf.rawPOB == 'Fargo N Dak', 'rawGCcoords'] = manualcoords

#trying .at instead, and checking data type as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949671/add-a-tuple-to-a-specific-cell-of-a-pandas-dataframe
gdf.dtypes
gdf.at[gdf.rawPOB == 'Fargo N Dak', 'rawGCcoords'] = manualcoords

# :(
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

P.S. In this example I could of course clean up the data before I try to geocode it, but I am trying to build a workflow in which I could use the mapped, first geocoding results to look for less obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's due to how you are indexing your GeoDataFrame.
When you are doing

`gdf.loc[gdf.rawPOB == 'Fargo N Dak', '_TEMP']` you get a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) in return (because you are using the [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) with `gdf.rawPOB == '..'`). So you can't do the assignement your are trying (and should get an error like *`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`* which isn't *that* helpful).

What I suggest is that you reindex your GeoDataFrame using your `rawPOB` column, then you will be able to easily set/get a value for a specific pair of (index, column name) using the [`DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) method like so :

```
gdf.set_index('rawPOB', inplace=True)

gdf.at['Fargo N Dak', '_TEMP'] = manualentry
gdf.at['Fargo N Dak', 'rawGCcoords'] = manualcoords
```

Once you are done, you can reset the index as previously if needed :

```
gdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the info, mgc, but I still get the same error. ```ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable```  The problem still seems to be the tuple that I'm trying to insert. ```gdf.loc['Fargo N Dak', 'rawGCcoords'] = 3``` works just fine.

Comment: ... I can also cast what I want to insert as a string and not get an error: ```gdf.loc['Fargo N Dak', '_TEMP'] = str(manualentry)``` but I'm concerned that will just cause problems further down the road.

Comment: @user2905280 my bad, it should work if, after re-indexing on the `rawPOB` column, you use the `at` method (I modified my answer). I just tested it on a fresh interpreter with pandas 1.0. by combining your code util the faulty line and the code from my answer.

Comment: _until* the faulty line_

Comment: This is so close to what I need. It works if there is only one instance in the geodataframe of the problematic place name. However, if 'Fargo N Dak' appears twice, as in `lst = ['Minneapolis MN', 'Fargo ND', 'Fargo N Dak','Fargo N Dak']`, the behaviour is very strange indeed, with `gdf['rawGCcoords'] [2]`  getting the longitude and `gdf['rawGCcoords'] [3]` getting the latitude. Is there a way to fix all the instances of 'Fargo N Dak' at once? To use `manualentry` and `manualcoords` in a one to many replacement?

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted mgc's answer as it does what I *asked*.  Thanks!

However, here's an alternative that a colleague came up with that does what I *want* because it can handle more than one instance of the same `rawPOB`, as when we set up the data like so:

```
`lst = ['Minneapolis MN', 'Fargo ND', 'Fargo N Dak', 'Fargo N Dak']

#and continue with...
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns =['rawPOB'])
df['_TEMP'] = df['rawPOB'].apply(lambda x: Ngeocoder(x, language='en',addressdetails=True))

df['rawGCcoords']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[1], x.point[0]) if x else None)
df['rawGClong']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[1]) if x else None)
df['rawGClat']=df['_TEMP'].apply(lambda x: (x.point[0]) if x else None)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['rawGClong'], 
df['rawGClat']))
manualentry= Ngeocoder('Fargo North Dakota', language='en',addressdetails=True)
manualcoords=(manualentry.point[1], manualentry.point[0])

#NEW PART:
gdf['unique_id'] = pd.RangeIndex(stop=gdf.shape[0])
df_NOK = gdf.loc[gdf['rawPOB'] == 'Fargo N Dak' ]
for index, row in df_NOK.iterrows():
    gdf.at[index, 'rawGCcoords'] = manualcoords
    gdf.at[index, '_TEMP'] = manualentry`
```