# How do I replace the content of an entire Pandas' cell with a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a row that contains the following:

```
id    animal
1     tiger
```

I would like to simply "set" the value of 1 to, say, "lion".

```
contains_latlong.iloc[1]["animal"]="lion"
```

is something that Pandas doesn't like. Being new, I'm getting mixed up with copying vs modifying dataframes, I suppose. The warning is

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

What is the way to set a given value of a cell? (And, in general, how should I think about this?)

**Edit**: `str.replace` is not what I'm looking for here. I just want to replace *the content* of that cell (whatever it is, rather than a regex), with some other string (literal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the approach is to use index and column identifiers:

```
df.loc[1, 'id'] = 'Lion'
```

yields

```
  animal    id
1  tiger  Lion
```

without any warnings.

Your example uses "`iloc`" rather than "`loc`", which means you need to access both columns and index by index, not name.  Something like `df.iloc[0, 0] = 'Lion'` might work in your example, assuming that you're showing a complete row without the index.

Comment: It still gives me the same warning using your method. Is there a way I'm not really working with cells/a dataframe?

Comment: What happens if you make your data frame with "df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':('tiger',), 'id':(1,)})" and then use "df.loc[0, 'id'] = 'Lion'" ?

Comment: to create my (what I think is) a dataframe, I do `df=pd.read_csv("some/file.csv")`... does that return a dataframe? (Thanks for your patience)

Comment: It creates a dataframe, but it is not certain that its structure (its index names and indices, its column names and order) will match the patterns used here.  What do you see with df.head()? (You may want to edit your question to show it there.)

Comment: Try check: `checkcontains_latlong.is_copy`. Is it True or False?

Comment: If it is `False`, you can turn off it - `contains_latlong.is_copy = False`