# How to set a value in a pandas DataFrame by mixed iloc and loc

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want a function that changes the value of a named column in a given row number of a DataFrame.
One option is to find the column's location and use iloc, like that:

```
def ChangeValue(df, rowNumber, fieldName, newValue):
    columnNumber = df.columns.get_loc(fieldName)
    df.iloc[rowNumber, columnNumber] = newValue
```

But I wonder if there is a way to use the magic of iloc and loc in one go, and skip the manual conversion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the columnIndex? won't `df.loc[rowIndex, fieldName] = newValue` just work?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The word 'index' was misleading, so I changed it. Assume the index  is not relevant here.

Comment: The fact remains why do you need this, if your df index values are already represented by whatever `rowNumber` is and `fieldName` is a column already then my first comment will just work

Comment: The index is irrelevant here. Example: I want to change a field in the first row of each group. The applied function f (in df.groupby(...).apply(f)) could use .iloc[0] and be ignorant about the index (which in this case would be the grouping fields).

Comment: I don't think you can do this as the indexing methods are specifically for either integer (iloc) or label based (loc) indexing, if you starting mixing both styles then you have to convert the integer<->label to do what you want

Comment: I don't know what the question is, but here's a great answer regarding `iloc/loc/ix`, and is probably relevant to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation  Also, a small sample dataset would help here and make the question more concrete.

Comment: @EdChum, are you idiot?

Answer (score 19):

I suggest just using `iloc` combined with the `Index.get_loc` method. eg:

```
df.iloc[0:10, df.columns.get_loc('column_name')]
```

A bit clumsy, but simple enough.

`MultiIndex` has both `get_loc` and `get_locs` which takes a sequence; unfortunately `Index` just seems to have the former.

Answer (score 8):

## Using `loc`

One has to resort to either employing [integer location `iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) all the way —as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55657149/2192488),— or using plain [location `loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) all the way, as shown here:

```
df.loc[df.index[[0, 7, 13]], 'column_name']
```

Comment: I needed to call [`df.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before using `df.index[]` to make sure I didn't have rows with the same index number.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/1389680),

> `ix` usually tries to behave like `loc` but falls back to behaving like `iloc` if the label is not in the index.

So you should especially be able to use `df.ix[rowNumber, fieldname]` in case `type(df.index) != type(rowNumber)`.

Comment: Note that `ix` has recently been made deprecated, so this solution will cause deprecation warnings.

Comment: ...which is a shame, because usually I _know_ how my dataframe looks...

Comment: @GustavLarsson So what's the current solution??

Comment: It seems like now you have to use `df.loc[df.index[[0, 2]], 'A']` to get the same behavior. Read more: https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Even it does not hold for each case, I'd like to add an easy one, if you are looking for top or bottom entries:

```
    df.head(1)['column_name']  # first entry in 'column_name'
    df.tail(5)['column_name']  # last 5 entries in 'column_name'
```

Comment: Neither generalizable nor an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: doing the following is not a good idea. I leave the answer as a counter example.

You can do this:

```
df.iloc[rowNumber].loc[fieldName] = newValue
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd

def ChangeValue(df, rowNumber, fieldName, newValue):
    df.iloc[rowNumber].loc[fieldName] = newValue

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
                  index=[4, 5, 6], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)
    A   B   C
4   0   2   3
5   0   4   1
6  10  20  30

ChangeValue(df, 1, "B", 999)
print(df)
    A    B   C
4   0    2   3
5   0  999   1
6  10   20  30
```

But **be careful**, if newValue is not the same type it does not work and will fail silently

```
ChangeValue(df, 1, "B", "Oops")
print(df)
    A    B   C
4   0    2   3
5   0  999   1
6  10   20  30
```

There is some good info about working with columns data types here: [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas/28648923#28648923)

Comment: Your answer suggests an [assignment with chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) which will result in a [`SettingWithCopy` warning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). This should be avoided by all means.

Comment: Yes knowing a bit more about pandas now, I agree.