# Write list to specific column in csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write the data from my `list` to just column 4

```
namelist = ['PEAR']

for name in namelist:
    for man_year in yearlist:
        for man_month in monthlist:
            with open('{2}\{0}\{1}.csv'.format(man_year,man_month,name),'w') as filename:
                writer = csv.writer(filename)
                writer.writerow(name)
                time.sleep(0.01)
```

it outputs to a csv like this

```
P             E                 A                R

4015854     234342            2442343            234242
```

How can I get it to go on just the 4th column?

```
                                                        PEAR

4015854     234342                2442343              234242
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the `name` to `csvwriter` it assumes the name as an iterable and write each character in a column.

So, for getting ride of this problem change the following line:

```
writer.writerow(name)
```

With:

```
writer.writerow([''] * (len(other_row)-1) + [name])
```

Here `other_row` can be one of the rest rows, but if you are sure about the length you can do something like:

```
writer.writerow([''] * (length-1) + [name])
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I remove the blank row between `PEAR` and the number data?

Comment: @iOSecure There is no blank row there.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line `writer.writerow(name)` with,

```
writer.writerow(['', '', '', name])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing '' to cells you don't want to touch, you could use df.at instead. For example, you could write df.at[index, ColumnName] = 10 which would change only the value of that specific cell.

You can read more about it here: [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)