# Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) posted earlier. The difference is that I want to change value in a cell that index column is not unique. For example:

```
   x  y
A  1  5
B  4  6
C  0  3
C  5  9
```

I want to replace 9 with 100 and get:

```
   x  y
A  1  5
B  4  6
C  0  3
C  5  100
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.ix['C', 'y'] = df.ix['C', 'y'].replace(9, 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for the ordinal indexes (they are always unique) like so:

```
In [13]: df.iloc[3, 1] = 100

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   x    y
A  1    5
B  4    6
C  0    3
C  5  100
```