# Editing a value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to:

Import a CSV of UPC codes into a dataframe. If the UPC code is 11 characters , append '0' to it. Ex: 19962123818  --> 019962123818

This is the code:

```
 #check UPC code length. If 11 characters, adds '0' before. If < 11 or > 13, throws Error
for index, row in clean_data.iterrows():
    if len(row['UPC']) == 11:
        row['UPC'] = ('0' + row['UPC'])
        #clean_data.set_value(row, 'UPC',('0' + (row['UPC']))
        print ("Edited UPC:", row['UPC'], type(row['UPC']))
    if len(row['UPC']) < 11 or len(row['UPC']) > 13:
        print ('Error, UPC length < 11 or > 13:')
        print ("Error in UPC:", row['UPC'])
        quit()
```

However, when I print the data, the original value is not edited:

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

I tried the set_value method as mentioned in other posts, but it didn't work.

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the vectorized approach, much cleaner! However, I get the following error, and the value is still not updating:

[image]

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: It is version 0.18.1

Comment: Sorry, indeed the error message suggests the correction, namely, to use `.loc[UPC_11_char, 'UPC']` though your `.ix` works just as well.

Answer (score 4):

Can I suggest a different method?

```
#identify the strings shorter than 11 characters
fix_indx = clean_data.UPC.astype(str).str.len()<11

#append these strings with a '0'
clean_data.loc[fix_indx] = '0'+clean_data[fix_indx].astype(str)
```

To fix the others, you can similarly do:

```
bad_length_indx = clean_data.UPC.astype(str).str.len()>13
clean_data.loc[bad_length] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `iterrows`documentation:

> 2. You should **never modify** something you are iterating over.    This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the    data
>      types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing    to
>      it will have no effect.

`row['UPC'] = ('0' + row['UPC'])` silently modifies a copy of the row, and `clean_data` is kept unmodified.

Do adopt a vectorized approach of your algorithm like @Gene is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. Thanks again for the vectorized idea. If anyone has this issue in the future, here's the code I used. Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) for more info.

```
UPC_11_char = clean_data.UPC.astype(str).str.len() == 11
clean_data.ix[UPC_11_char, 'UPC'] = '0' + clean_data[UPC_11_char]['UPC'].astype(str)

print clean_data[UPC_11_char]['UPC']
```