# Pandas how to use .loc when I have a MultiIndexed column?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I wrote a short code to illustrate what's confusing me:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [0.2,0.4]
f = np.linspace(0.0,4.0,5)

mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,f], names=['a', 'f'])
df = pd.DataFrame(dtype=float, index=range(0,100), columns=mindex)
```

For the printed structure of the DataFrame, see the EDIT. Now, I want to know how to specifically use `.loc` to assign a value to a specific element. Apparently, the following:

```
print(df.loc[0, 0.2, 0.0])
```

gives the me error:

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

but I don't understand why? The following two statements work as expected:

```
print(df.loc[0])
print(df.loc[0,0.2])
```

with `print(df.loc[0,0.2])` for example outputting:

```
f
0.0   NaN
1.0   NaN
2.0   NaN
3.0   NaN
4.0   NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

But how to I get that final `f=0.0` value out?

Also, my next idea would have been to use a tuple for the column index, but `print(df.loc[0,[0.2,0.0]])` doesn't work either.

---

EDIT: Just to clarify the structure of my DataFrame.

```
print(df)
```

gives:

```
a  0.2                 0.4                
f  0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
...
```

---

EDIT 2: Just to update after the comments, basically two suggestions were to use `df.loc[0][0.2][0.0]` or `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0]`. However, since I need this to assign values to specific elements, both of those seem to be discouraged by pandas (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

In fact, `df.loc[0][0.2][0.0] = 2` seems to work, but `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0] = 2` doesn't (because it returns a copy of a slice instead of a view).

Comment: Does df.loc[0][0.2][0.0] work in your case?

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to assign with that since it would return copy-slices and now views though right? I.e `df[0][0.2][0.0] = ...` wouldn't work. Ok, nevermind, I just tried it and it works for assignment. That confuses me I thought it was discourage to make assignments that way.

Comment: It did edit the original df for me. pandas 0.18.1

Comment: I see, it seems to work, I'm just surprised it does. According to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy this is discouraged right?

Comment: Sorry are you after `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0]`?

Comment: That would be the same element as `df.loc[0][0.2][0.0]`, but like I said, I always thought pandas encourages using `loc` rather than sub-indexing because it can mess you up if it returns a copy instead of a view.

Comment: Looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe, perhaps the best way is to use `df.set_value`

Comment: If you really want to loc, as EdChum suggested, you can do `df.loc[0,0.2].loc[0]`.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon that isn't the same as `df.loc[0][0.2][0.0]`, this is chained indexing, whilst `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0]` explicitly selects a column and then returns the row value matching that index label

Comment: EdChum's thing doesn't work, while the suggestion you (Xin) posted allows assignment to values in the DataFrame, EdChum's version: `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0]` suffers from the problem I mentioned, it ends up returning a copy, and assignment won't work. Try `df[[(0.2,0.0)]].loc[0] = 2.0`, it doesn't work (for me).

Comment: Hmm, this does work `df.ix[0,[(0.2,0.0)]]` but it's going to be deprecated in 0.20.0, I think therefore you want `df.loc[0, (0.2,0)]` this does work for me

Comment: For multiindices, use tuples to define your required location like `df.loc[0, (0.2, 0)]`. This is the recommended way.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see what it was now. Apparently it needs to be one of those `(,..)` tuples, and not a list like I was using. Thanks for the help.