# Set values for particular columns in a row of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Referring to [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe/13842286#13842286) I see

```
 df.set_value( rownum, colnum, 'Someval')
```

to set a given cell.  Assume in my dataframe all the columns are integers.

Is there a way to use

```
set_value
```

to set a range of columns in a given row, or do I need a different function?

```
df.set_value ( rownum, colstart:colend, 'someval')
```

gave a syntax error.

After some contortion I found this:

```
df.ix[ rownum , colstart:colend] = 'Someval'
```

This one works but I was wondering about set_value or perhaps some other short way.

Comment: You are looking for `df.iloc[ rownum , colstart:colend] = 'Someval'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted directly above by [@MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707078/set-values-for-particular-columns-in-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe#comment72535969_42707078), you are looking for

```
df.iloc[ rownum , colstart:colend] = 'Someval'
```

Comment: This works; note:   I noticed comparing the two that  df.ix [ row, colstart:colend ] = 'someval' includes colend while df.iloc [ row, colstart:colend ] = 'someval' does not include colend.

Comment: Yep - .iloc is specifically for integer column values. Also, note that the pandas docs generally favor using .loc as a successor to .ix