# Iterate over pairwise combinations of column names and row indices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following `pandas` `DataFrame` :

```
>>> df

  x y z

x 1 3 0

y 0 5 0

z 0 3 4
```

I want to iterate over the pairwise combinations of column names and row indices to perform certain operation. For example, for the pair of `x` and `y`, replace the 3 with 'xy'. The desired output will look like:

```
>>> df

   x  y z

x xx xy xz

y xy yy yz

z xz yz zz
```

a naïve code that I tried and doesn't work is:

```
for i, j in range(0,2):
    df.loc[df.index[i], df.columns[j]] = df.index[i] + df.columns[j]
```

Comment: Check out my answer and this link : `df.set_value()` is far and away faster, link to why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe/24517695#24517695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> df
   x  y  z
x  1  3  0
y  0  5  0
z  0  3  4

>>> for i in range(3):
...     for j in range(3):
...         df.loc[df.index[i], df.columns[j]] = df.index[i] + df.columns[j]
...
>>> df
    x   y   z
x  xx  xy  xz
y  yx  yy  yz
z  zx  zy  zz
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Couldn't get me head around it.

Answer (score 10):

How about a simple one-liner, using Pandas DataFrame elements:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.index+x.name)
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z
x  xx  xy  xz
y  yx  yy  yz
z  zx  zy  zz
```

#### Update:  Using numpy.ufunc.outer method.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(df.index, df.columns), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z
x  xx  xy  xz
y  yx  yy  yz
z  zx  zy  zz
```

Comment: This is clever !

Comment: Really nice solution +1

Comment: getting this error: `TypeError: ('can only perform ops with scalar values', 'occurred at index x')` any idea why?

Comment: TypeError happens because the dtype of the column index and index are not the same and so.  To fix this error you need to cast the dtype to the same dtype. if you want string addition or integer addition. Use astype.

Answer (score 2):

`df.set_value()` is way faster, link to why: [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe/24517695#24517695)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}, {'x': 7, 'y': 8, 'z': 9}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')

df = df.astype(str)

df

#       x   y   z
#    0  1   2   3
#    1  4   5   6
#    2  7   8   9


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in list(df.columns.values):
        val = str(idx) + str(column)
        df.set_value(idx, column, val)

df
```

output:

```
    x   y   z
0   0x  0y  0z
1   1x  1y  1z
2   2x  2y  2z
```

Note: set_value won't work if column names are not unique https://github.com/cm3/lafayettedb_thumbnail_getter/issues/3 . You will have to separately fix the non_unique column name problem.

If you don't care about column names you can prepone it with column #

```
df.columns = [str(idx) + '_' + name for idx, name in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: do you know how to implement it when I have duplicated column names?

Comment: `set_value` won't work in column names are not unique https://github.com/cm3/lafayettedb_thumbnail_getter/issues/3 . You will have to separately fix the non_unique column name problem.

Comment: @VikashSingh I was revisiting some old posts and this is your solution for the TypeError using my answer.  `df.apply(lambda x: x.index.astype(str)+x.name)`  index and column need to be same dtype and have an add method for that dtype.

Answer (score 1):

This should be really fast:

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.meshgrid(df.columns.values.astype(str),
                   df.index.values.astype(str))
result = np.core.defchararray.add(*grid)
```

You can then assign `result` to either the same dataframe or another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(df[i][col] + df[col][i])


df = pd.DataFrame(df[i][col] + df[col][i] for i, col in enumerate(df.columns))
```

This way you can iterate over all the columns and paired rows dynamically without needing to know how many columns there are.