# Read or Write items from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure how to phrase my search in order to find it so this is probably a duplicate. Please feel free to point me in the right direction.

In pandas, I know that I can use `iloc` to grab particular pieces of a dataframe.

I'm curious to know if there is a way to Read or Write particular items from said dataframe. 

In one case, I could get `item08` by using `(1, 1)` and then reading it

Or perhaps I want `item28` I could use `(2, 4)`

Maybe I'd like to change `item22` on `(2, 3)`

```
  +--------------------------------------------+
0 | item01 | item07 | item13 | item19 | item26 |
  +--------------------------------------------+
1 | item02 | item08 | item14 | item21 | item27 |
  +--------------------------------------------+
2 | item03 | item09 | item15 | item22 | item28 |
  +--------------------------------------------+
3 | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    |
  +--------------------------------------------+
      0         1        2        3        4
```

How can this be done?

Comment: By push or pull, do you mean read/write, I'm not quite sure I follow your terminology

Comment: I think that's what I mean. I'm still new to Pandas, so please forgive me if I use bad terminology

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe#13842286) answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read

```
in[1]: df.iloc[0,0]
out[1]: item01
```

write

```
in[2]: df.iloc[0,0] = item99
in[3]: df.iloc[0,0]
out[3]: item99
```

Comment: When writing, is this the fastest way to do this. The answer that @jjj had provided mentioned something about `.set_value`. Is there a right or wrong way of doing this?

Comment: That answer hasn't been updated in a year,  `set_value` is depreciated as stated in the answer, `ix` is also depreciated. The pandas doc say that `.at` is similar to `.loc`