# Pandas : Replace values multiple times until the end

Tags: python, pandas, replace, series, shift

I have a pandas df like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[114,114,114,113,12,10,8500,8666]})
```

[image]

It is cumulative data from sales. 
There is a bug in the data : Some observations are wrong.
(No value can be greater than the previous one : i.e., 8500 and 8666 are not correct)
I want to replace these values with the previous one.

I tried this

```
df['above'] = df.sales.shift(1)
df.loc[df.above < df.sales, 'sales'] = df.above
```

But this code works only one time, how to extend this code to replace all values until the end of the series (with the previous one) ?

The desired result should looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace values to `NaN`s by condition and then use `ffill` - [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`:

```
df.loc[df.above < df.sales, 'sales'] = np.nan
df['sales'] = df['sales'].ffill()
print (df)
   sales   above
0  114.0     NaN
1  114.0   114.0
2  114.0   114.0
3  113.0   114.0
4   12.0   113.0
5   10.0    12.0
6   10.0    10.0
7   10.0  8500.0
```

What is same as using [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), which by default replace to `NaN`s, last cast to `int` if always integer values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[114,114,114,113,12,10,8500,8666]})

df['sales'] = df['sales'].mask(df.sales.shift(1) < df.sales).ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
   sales
0    114
1    114
2    114
3    113
4     12
5     10
6     10
7     10
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[114,114,114,113,12,10,8500,8400]})

df['sales'] = df['sales'].mask((df.sales.shift(1) < df.sales).cumsum() > 0).ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
   sales
0    114
1    114
2    114
3    113
4     12
5     10
6     10
7     10
```

Detail:

```
print ((df.sales.shift(1) < df.sales).cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
Name: sales, dtype: int32

print ((df.sales.shift(1) < df.sales).cumsum() > 0)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
Name: sales, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work when a value is lower than the value above : for example with this df = pd.DataFrame({'sales':[114,114,114,113,12,10,8500,8400]})

Comment: So I think if `cumulative data` it is not possible. Please give me some time.

Comment: One question, do you need replace from first `True`s of mask to end of DataFrame?

Comment: yes ............Because the bug appears only at the end of the series (but the values are weird.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
df.loc[df['sales'] > 200] = 10
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467449/4772042

'200' is the proper value I caught. Change it to the desired value.