# Python: How to write to a specific position in a pandas table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Pandas table:

```
       Type    A    B    C   AB   AC   BC  ABC  
0  mean(+1)  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1  mean(-1)  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                 
2     slope  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

considering "mean(+1)" as another column with its header name as "Type" in a different column. and "ABC" as a column header, so how do I write to the position in the coordinates [mean(+1), ABC]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Index` for axis 0 and a boolean mask to figure this out:

```
ax0 = df.index[df['Type'] == 'mean(+1)']
df.loc[ax0, 'ABC']
```

returns the `NaN` corresponding with index `0` and column `'ABC'`:

```
0   NaN
Name: ABC, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Alex,
thanks, you have me the directions! 

I wrote:

df.at[df["Type"]=="mean(+1)","ABC"] = 1.0

Thanks!

Comment: For performance, I recommend using `pd.DataFrame.iat`, which requires integer locations. This may involve a small amount of extra code to map to integer locations.

Comment: You could just use ``df.loc[df.Type == 'mean(+1)', 'ABC']``.