# Python SettingWithCopyWarning, but I'm trying to set the value using .ix

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in python and I'm trying to modify a specific value in a particular row.  I found a solution to this problem [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index), but it is still generating the SettingWithCopy error.

The name of the data frame is internal_df and it has columns 'price', 'visits', and 'orders'. Specifically, I want to add the number of orders and visits to a lower price point if we don't have a sufficient number of visits (100 in this example).  Note that below the variable 'price' is a float, and the data types for 'price' within the internal_df data frame is float, while price and orders are ints.

```
if int(internal_df[internal_df['price']==price]['visits']) < 100:
 for index, row in internal_df.iterrows():
   if float(row['price']) > price:
      internal_df.ix[internal_df['price'] == price, 'visits'] = internal_df.ix[internal_df['price'] == price, 'visits'] + row['visits']
      internal_df.ix[internal_df['price'] == price, 'orders'] = internal_df.ix[internal_df['price'] == price, 'orders'] + row['orders']
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
    price   visits  sales
0   1399.99 2   0
1   169.99  2   0
2   99.99   1   0
3   99.99   1   0
4   139.99  1   0
5   319.99  1   0
6   198.99  1   0
7   119.99  1   0
8   39.99   1   0
9   259.98  1   0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, or should I just ignore the error?

Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`.ix` is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix) because it indexes by position *or* by label, depending on the data type of the index. Use `.loc` or `.iloc` instead.

This `SettingWithCopyWarning` might originate from a "get" operation several lines of code above what you've provided. A quick fix might be to find where `internal_df` is first assigned, and to add `.copy()` to the end of the assignment statement. For example, if you have `internal_df = df[df['colname'] <= value]`, change that to `internal_df = df[df['colname'] <= value].copy()` and hopefully that resolves the error.

Also, I think you can do what you're trying to do without a for loop, which would be faster and more readable!