# Pandas Dataframe For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to replace a column in a pandas dataframe with a portion of another column. What I have so far is:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  File = df.at[row, 'FileName']
  df.at[row, 'NUMBER'] = File.split(".")[1]
```

Ideally, this will iterate through rows of the dataframe and replace the number column with a portion of the FileName column

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: At based indexing on an integer index can only have integer indexers

and I think it has to do with the misuse of df.at[], but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont loop by `iterrows` because [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002), better is use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with selecting second lists by indexing:

```
df['NUMBER'] = df['FileName'].str.split(".").str[1]
```

Or use `list comprehension` if need better performance:

```
df['NUMBER'] = [x.split(".")[1] for x in df['FileName']]
```

Comment: Your solution is objectively better than what I was doing. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are wondering about error

change  `df.at[row, 'NUMBER']` to `df.at[index, 'NUMBER']` it should be `index` instead of `row` which is whole dataframe

it should be like this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

  df.at[index, 'NUMBER'] = row['FileName'].split(".")[1]
```

[for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

I prefer jezrael's answer for solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is "split" in combination with "expand=True". Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
col_1 = ['abc', 'abc', 'bcd', 'bcd']
col_2 = ['james.25', 'jane.23', 'andrew.15', 'jim.22']
data = pd.DataFrame({'NUMBER': col_1, 'FileName': col_2})

data['NUMBER'] = data['FileName'].str.split('.', expand=True)[1]
```