# Replacing values that match certain string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace certain data in the data frame to include the additional 'F'.

The code should look like this:

```
if testdata['pfType'] =='NK225M'|testdata['pfType'] == 'TOPIXM':
    testdata['pfType'] = ' testdata['pfType'] & 'F';
```

I tried to do this:

```
testdata['pfType'][testdata['pfType'] == 'NK225M'] = 'NK225MF'
testdata['pfType'][testdata['pfType'] == 'TOPIXM'] = 'TOPIXMF'
```

But it is not changing the values, what is the best way to add the 'F' to the strings if it is NK225M or TOPIXM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test values of list and if match condition add `F`:

```
testdata = pd.DataFrame({'pfType':['NK225M','TOPIXM','AAA']})

vals = ['NK225M','TOPIXM']
testdata.loc[testdata['pfType'].isin(vals), 'pfType'] += 'F'
print (testdata)
    pfType
0  NK225MF
1  TOPIXMF
2      AAA
```

Another solutions with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
testdata['pfType'] = testdata['pfType'].mask(testdata['pfType'].isin(vals),
                                             testdata['pfType'] + 'F')
```

---

```
testdata['pfType'] = np.where(testdata['pfType'].isin(vals), 
                              testdata['pfType'] + 'F', 
                              testdata['pfType'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy.where`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testdata = pd.DataFrame({"pfType": ['NK225M', 'TOPIXM', "Hello", "World"]})
testdata['pfType'] = np.where((testdata['pfType'] == "TOPIXM") | (testdata['pfType'] == 'NK225M'), testdata['pfType']+"F", testdata['pfType'])
print(testdata)
```

**Output:**

```
    pfType
0  NK225MF
1  TOPIXMF
2    Hello
3    World
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`

```
testdata['pfType'] = np.where(testdata['pfType']=='NK225M', 'NK225MF', testdata['pfType'])
testdata['pfType'] = np.where(testdata['pfType']=='TOPIXM', 'TOPIXMF', testdata['pfType'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify dataframe use below code.

```
  testdata.at['pfType', testdata['pfType'] == 'NK225M'] = 'NK225MF'
```

([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index).)