# How to modify (correct) values that are poorly written in a DataFrame with python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a csv file that contains values that are badly written.
I want to correct these mistakes. for example replace Toyouta by toyota, maxda by mazda, in the column named carCompany. [image: example].

The job I need to do is to predict the car price using these independent variables [image: the beginning of my code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Comment: you could use this package : https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/ very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad')

```
eg.
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
...                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
...                    'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
>>> df.replace(0, 5)
   A  B  C
0  5  5  a
1  1  6  b
2  2  7  c
3  3  8  d
4  4  9  e

df.replace('Toyouta','toyota')
```

should work.

Comment: it works but the change is not preserved. how can I keep it to continue my analyzes

Comment: just overwrite DataFrame: df = df.replace('Toyouta','toyota'), or create new one: df_new=df.replace('Toyouta','toyota')

Comment: df.replace({'Toyouta':'toyota', 'vw': 'volkswagen'}, inplace = True)