# Set specific value to the created filtered column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Question is how can I set value to the **specific** rows of just created column?
I can do

```
df['New_column'] = np.nan
df['New_columns][df['Old_column'] > 20] = SPECIFIC_VALUE
```

But I cannot do it without predefining new column as nan:

```
df['New_columns][df['Old_column'] > 20] = SPECIFIC_VALUE ### That gives me error
```

Is there way to do such operation without "predefining"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['Old_column'] > 20, 'New_columns'] = SPECIFIC_VALUE
```

If want set 2 new values use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['New_Columns'] = np.where(df['Old_column'] > 20,SPECIFIC_VALUE, np.nan)
```