# How to change specific row value in dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here I attached my data frame.I am trying to change specific value of row.but I am not getting succeed.Any leads would be appreciated.

```
df.replace(to_replace ="Agriculture, forestry and fishing   ", 
             value ="Agriculture")
```

[Image of My data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTPpe.png)

Comment: take a look [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('Agriculture, forestry and fishing', 'Agriculture')
```

Comment: `@Mayank Porwel` thanks a ton!  for providing easy solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any data type:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Name']=='Agriculture, forestry and fishing', 'Name'] = 'Agriculture'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get all the columns names with calling: df.columns
then you can copy this list and replace the name of any column and reassign the list to df.columns.
For example:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200]], columns=['A', 'B'])
    df.columns
```

the output will be in a jupyter notebook: 
Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')

so you copy that list and then replace what you want to change and reassign it

```
    df.columns = ['C', 'D']
```

and then you will get a dataframe with the name of columns changed from A and B to C and D, you check this by calling

```
    df.head()
```