# Use pandas and pandastable to insert value into selected cell

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a `pandastable` that displays in my `tkinter` GUI.

Using the value from the `tkinter` option menu, `value = Status.get()` I would like to select a particular cell in my `pandastable` and use the value from `value = Status.get()` to append the cell.

I know how I can append a value to a `dataframe` using `set_value()` within a function but Im not sure on how I can return the position of the selected cell using `pandastable`? Or if its possible?

I have played with `tkinter treeview` widget and you can return selected cell position with `.focus()`

I have been referencing methods using the doc: **https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.get_col_clicked**

But I cant find anything to fit my purpose...

See below the screenshot of my `pandastable` the `Column Current Status` `row 2` position has been double clicked. I want to return this position.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.title('Workshop Manager')


def select_input_file():
    global df, app
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode=INSIDE, height=500, width=2000, x=0, y=50)
    df = app.table.model.df

    

class TestApp(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, input_file_path, editable = True, enable_menus = False):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.table = Table(self, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
        self.table.importCSV(input_file_path)
        self.table.show(input_file_path)
        self.table.addColumn('Current Status')
        self.table.addColumn('Assign Technician')
        self.table.autoResizeColumns()



def set_cell():
    row = app.table.getSelectedRow()
    col = app.table.getSelectedColumn()
    app.table.model.setValueAt(Status.get(), row, col)
    app.table.redraw()

StatusList = [
    "Carry Over",
    "Waiting On Parts",
    "Waiting On Car Wash",
    "Yet to Arrive",
    "Not Started",
    "Being Worked On",
]

Status = StringVar()
Status.set(0)


drop=tk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command = set_cell())
drop.place(x=1440, y=0, height=50, width=150)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: pandastable screenshot]

Comment: This question [set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index) may help.

Comment: Very useful thread, great info. I cant find anything in there for this particular purpose? Ive updated question with a screenshot. Hope it tells a better story.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to update the selected cell:

```
def set_cell():
    row = app.table.getSelectedRow()
    col = app.table.getSelectedColumn()
    app.table.model.setValueAt(Status.get(), row, col)
    app.table.redraw()
```

where `app` is the instance of `TestApp` created inside `select_input_file()` function.  You need to declare it global inside the function:

```
def select_input_file():
    global df, app
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode=INSIDE, height=500, width=2000, x=0, y=50)
    df = app.table.model.df
```

Also you need to find a way to call the `set_cell()` function, the easy way is to use button.

---

*Update:* If you use the `command` option of `OptionMenu`, like below:

```
drop=tk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command=set_cell)
```

You need to change the `set_cell()` function as below:

```
def set_cell(val):
    row = app.table.getSelectedRow()
    col = app.table.getSelectedColumn()
    app.table.model.setValueAt(val, row, col)
    app.table.redraw()
```

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive answer,  but I am getting error `AttributeError: module 'pandastable.app' has no attribute 'table'` using `drop=tk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command = set_cell())`

Comment: @JamesCook The callback of `command` option of `OptionMenu` will be passed an argument, the selected item.  See my update answer.

Comment: Sorry I should have picked up on that... Thank you, very much. Again, a great help