# Pandas assign value to a filtered dataframe/series. Why not consistent?

Tags: python, pandas

TL;DR: Use `.loc[:, 'foo']` instead of `.foo`

---

**When does pandas assign values to the view and when does it assign values to the copy?**

AFAIK, pandas either returns view or copy, depending on the method you use.

You can change the original dataframe if you assign a value to the view but you can't change the original if a value is assigned to the copy.

However, below behavior confuses me. Why is assigning value to a view works with a dataframe but not with a series?

```
dd = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 3},
])

dd[dd.a == 1] = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 100, 'b': 200}]) # Assigning value works. 

dd
>>  a   b
0   100 200
1   2   4
2   4   3
```

As expected, the value of the first row has been changed.

However, as seen below, assigning a value to a series doens't work, even thought the settings are identical except that I called a series.

```
dd = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 3},
])

dd[dd.a == 1].a = 1000 # Assigning value doesn't work.  

dd
>>  a   b
0   1   2
1   2   4
2   4   3
```

I'm on pandas 0.19.1 though. (Cause I'm using Python 2.7)

Comment: Please dont use python 2.7 since its officially dead. Pretty much none of the users who will assist you here can assist you in python 2.7

Comment: IIUC, you need use `.loc` or `iloc` to assign values - i.e `dd.loc[dd['a'] == 1, 'a'] = 1000` which returns new view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Not up to me. Some companies, including mine, have too many legacy codes so they still have to stick to Python 2. It's a lot of pain in a deprecated version of the language but it's something I have to deal with.

Comment: ah, I understand then. There are a lot of new users on SO who end up using 2.7 because they find some old tutorials. But this is something you can't do much about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR;**

I think you have answered your question yourself. Assigning values to a view will behave the way you are expecting while assigning values to a copy will NOT modify the original data frame.

In essence;

- `dd[dd.a == 1].a` is a copy of a value from the slice of dataframe
- `dd.a[dd.a == 1]` is a view of a slice (by condition) of another slice (df.a) of the same dataframe.

---

The following is a conditional slice of the dataframe `dd` and therefore its a view of the dataframe. Similarly the one with `loc`, which is the recommended way.

```
dd[dd.a == 1] #Slice of a dataframe based on condition returned as a view

dd.loc[dd.a == 1] #Slice of a dataframe based on condition returned as a view
```

When you pull a specific column from this slice, you end up getting a copy -

```
dd[dd.a == 1].a = 100 
#This syntax basically says - 
#From the view of a slice of dd, give me values of 'a' and set that to 100"
#The assignment here is that to a copy and not to a view
```

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  4  3
```

Therefore assignment will have no effect on the original dataframe.

If you want to do assignment for a specific column then you need to do this -

```
dd.a[dd.a == 1] = 100
#This syntax basically says - 
#"From the slice, dd.a give me aother slice based on condition and set that slice to 100"
#The assignment happens a sliced view of the dataframe itself
```

```
     a  b
0  100  2
1    2  4
2    4  3
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Perfectly explained! I had a vague picture of how Pandas handle copy/view of a dataframe.

Comment: glad to help. if you play around with this a bit you can really see some more intricacies that are part of this topic.

Comment: I honestly did not know that `dd[dd.a == 1].a` and `dd.a[dd.a == 1]` have different behaviours