# Can't update values in Pandas dataframe when NaN values present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the code here

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,20], [30, 40], [50, 60]],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

it outputs

```
   max_speed  shield
0         10      20
1         30      40
2         50      60
```

Changing a value here, I can easily do

```
df.iloc[1]['shield'] = 5
```

outputting

```
   max_speed  shield
0         10      20
1         30       5
2         50      60
```

However, if there are NaN values present in the dataframe, I can't change the values anymore.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10], [30, 40], [50, 60]],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

```
   max_speed  shield
0         10     NaN
1         30    40.0
2         50    60.0
```

```
df.iloc[1]['shield'] = 5
```

```
   max_speed  shield
0         10     NaN
1         30    40.0
2         50    60.0
```

I understand I can use fillna() and others, but would like to know in this particular case what I can do. I want to fill a larger dataset's NaN values with the next rows value where I don't think these can help me e.g. [0]['shield'] = 40

Comment: While I can't exactly explain why this is happening, `df.loc[1, 'shield'] = 5 ` will do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the chained assignement. Please read more [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/).

To avoid this simply put the chained operations into a single operation like:

```
df.loc[1, 'shield'] = 5
```