# add value to first cell in a new df column in python

Tags: python, pandas, columnsorting

I have the below code which adds the value across every cell but what i want is to create a new column called one_way_turnover and only add the value to the first cell not every cell. can someone help me please?

```
df[:, 'one_way_turnover'] = (df[col_name].abs.sum()) / 2
```

Comment: Please refer to the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index).

Comment: what do you want to have in the other cells? NaNs, emptry strings?

Comment: i tried this but doesn't work as its not a pre existing column

Comment: nan please if possible

Comment: then try sth like this `df['one_way_turnover'] = np.nan; df['one_way_turnover'].iloc[0] = (df[col_name].abs.sum()) / 2`

Comment: legend, thanks a lot!