# Setting particular values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with lots of values (just either 0 or 1). I have the table currently with just 0s and if a certain intersection (of that row and column) is true, I want to change that value to 1.
For example, if my dataframe looks like this and I want to access the X element to assign a particular value to it.

```
ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
A  |   |   |   |   |
B  |   |   | X |   |
C  |   |   |   |   |
```

The code I used is `df[3][df['ID'] == 'B'] = 1`, however instead of just changing that particular value (marked X in the dataframe) to 1, it changes all the values in the column named 3.

Am I using the wrong syntax or logic here? Any answers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `df['ID'] == 'B'` returns a bool, yeah ?

Comment: Maybe just use `df[3]['B'] = 1` or `df[3][df['ID']] = 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Comment: you could create minimal working code with example data in code (as `df = DataFrame(...)`) - so we could see if you use it correctly in this code, and if you keep data in correct way. And we could use this code to test solutions.

Comment: maybe first you should use `print()` to see what you really selected using `df[3][df['ID'] == 'B']`

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), index='A B C'.split(), columns='1 2 3'.split())
```

You can use **replace** for a specific value

```
df['2'].replace(4, 'X', inplace=True)
```

But your approach also worked in my example

```
df['3'][df.index == 'B'] = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fast and simple method:

#original DF:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0],\
                    'B': [0,0,0],\
                    'C': [0,0,0]})
df1 = df1.transpose()
df1
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Code to locate the cell and set the new value with the `.at()`:

```
df1.at['B', 1] = '1'
df1
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 0 |