# Pandas, changing the value of the column based off the row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with the logic for a dataframe problem.
The existing dataframe I have looks like this

```
SN      BC        2051   2052    2053   2054   ...
113     NO          Y    N         N     
224     NO            
335     NO          Y    N                N
446     NO          Y    N          N     N 
557     NO          N    Y          Y
```

I need help with the changing row 224. I need a line of code that will change the value in the BC column from NO to YES if the rest of the row is empty.It seems simple but I am new to pandas, and trying to learn.
Ive tried writing .apply and lambdas, but no luck yet.
The finished dataframe should look like

```
SN      BC        2051   2052    2053   2054   ...
113     NO          Y    N         N     
224     YES            
335     NO          Y    N                N
446     NO          Y    N          N     N 
557     NO          N    Y          Y
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index)

Comment: Not really, I dont understand how to apply the logic I need through that example.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'SN': [113, 224, 335, 446, 557], 
         'BC': ['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 
         '2051': ['Y', None, 'Y', 'Y', 'N'], 
         '2052': ['N', None, 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 
         '2053': ['N', None, 'N', 'N', 'Y'], 
         '2054': [None, None, None, 'N', None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

`df`

[image]

**Code**

```
cond = df.iloc[:, 2:].isna().all(axis=1)
df['BC'] = df['BC'].mask(cond, 'YES')
```

df:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using `apply` you can use a ternary operator to set a condition when updating.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "SN": [113, 224, 335, 446, 557],
    "BC": ["NO", "NO", "NO", "NO", "NO"],
    "2051": ["Y", "", "Y", "Y", "N"],
    "2052": ["N", "", "N", "N", "Y"],
    "2053": ["N", "", "", "N", "Y"],
    "2054": ["", "", "N", "N", "Y"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["BC"] = df.apply(lambda row: "YES" if (row[2:] == "").all() else row["BC"], axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```py
    SN   BC 2051 2052 2053 2054
0  113   NO    Y    N    N
1  224  YES
2  335   NO    Y    N         N
3  446   NO    Y    N    N    N
4  557   NO    N    Y    Y    Y
```